# Google Compute Engine - troubleshooting SSH "Connection refused"

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

I am using the following command to access my instance on Google Compute Engine:

```
gcutil ssh my-instance-name
```

but it gives me this error:

```
ssh: connect to host ip-address port 22: Connection refused
```

I checked and deactivated the firewall, but I am still getting this error. Can someone please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: You appear to be referring to Google Compute Engine, not App Engine or Cloud Storage.

Comment: yes i was referred but i cant fix this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Compute Engine firewall blocks all traffic unless there is a rule to allow it.
The most common issue is missing the default firewall rule which allows SSH. To add it back, run:

```
gcutil --project=myproject addfirewall --allowed=tcp:22 default-ssh
```

If that isn't it, there is some good advice for troubleshooting SSH connection issues in the docs: 
[Troubleshooting SSH errors](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#ssherrors)

Comment: If you created a network instead of using the project "default" network you may have run into this and you would run the command Brian mentions on the network you created by adding --network=new-network.

Answer (score 0):

Google Compute Engine firewall also have to define "Network".

For custon "Network":

```
gcutil --project=yourproject addfirewall --allowed=tcp:22 default-ssh --network yournetwork
```